# Modelling the probability of the game outcome

Tags: probability

Firstly, I apologise, because I'm no mathematician! But I have a game who's outcomes are in points and could be anywhere between 0 and 50,000, but the interval between game scores is 100 points. I've drawn something that I consider to a bad layman's attempt at graphing the probability distribution of the game outcomes. I guess it looks a bit like a log normal distribution but won't meet at zero on the x & y axes.

In my example, the probability of getting a zero score would be 5%. The mode of the curve of game outcomes is 800 points (10% probability), and then the probability tails off close to zero right out to 50,000.

What I'd like to do is to be able to model such a distribution (roughly) so when I'm modelling a player going through many games I can get a sense of how their scores will change game by game and their cumulative score will grow. So for each new game, I'd like to model a game outcome by selecting a random game outcome based on the probability curve.

Hope this makes sense. Anything in the right direction would do. Doesn't have to be perfect.

I'm using Excel btw so any pointers on how to do this in Excel would be gratefully received.

TIA

[distribution of game outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njsix.jpg)

Comment: Looks like either a hypergeometric distribution or a gamma distribution to me.

Comment: Can you describe how the game is played (how the point score is determined) as that might suggest the type of distribution?